# Energy states of particle in potential $V(x,y)= x^2 + y^2 + xy$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

How can I find the energy of a particle in a 2D potential of form $V(x,y)= x^2 + y^2 + xy$? It looks to have a close relation with Quantum Harmonic Oscillators, is it related to it? What could we say about its ground state energy?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
x^2+y^2+xy = \frac34 (x+y)^2 + \frac14 (x-y)^2.
$$
This means that if you transform to the new variables
\begin{align}
\xi & = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(x+y) \\
\eta & = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(x-y),
\end{align}
and with a similar transformation from $p_x,p_y$ to $p_\xi,p_\eta$ to make sure that $[\xi,p_\xi] = i = [\eta,p_\eta]$ and $[\xi,p_\eta] = 0 = [\eta,p_\xi]$, your hamiltonian will be drastically simplified, to the point that you can just read off the spectrum from its structure.

Comment: More generally, this method works for an arbitrary potential which is a quadratic form.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.